# Trying to figure a phrase I've been hearing: ななじゅっと

Tags: phrases

Recently I've been hearing people around me use a phrase that sounds like "ななじゅっと" especially in the morning when talking about the days plans. I can't seem to find anything on a dictionary - just leads to an entry for seventy which I am pretty sure is not what they are saying is.

Any help?

Comment: How did they use it (sentence context)?

Comment: Second part is probably ずっと, which means to do continuously, like "I'll be doing papers all morning."

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out that they are referring to the building number that we are in, which is 70. So they are saying something like 七十棟｛ななじゅっとう}　to mean building 70